# Why is it that $\inf_{x∈E} d(x, a) > 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

Suppose $X$ is a metric space, $E ⊂ X$ is closed, and $a$ is a point not in $E$.

Why is it that

$$\inf_{x∈E} d(x, a) > 0$$

?

Comment: Since $E$ is closed its complemet $X\setminus E$ is open. This is equivalent to the fact that you find for every $x \notin E$ an $\varepsilon >0$, such that the open ball $B_{\varepsilon}(x)$ has empty intersection with $E$, so $d(x,E) \ge \varepsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

If there are points $x_n\in E$ arbitrarily close to $a$ then there is a subsequence of the $x_n$ that converges to $a$ so $a$ is in the closure of $E.$

Answer (score 0):

As $X \setminus E$ is open, and $a$ is in it, there is some $r>0$ such that $B(a,r) \subseteq X \setminus E$, or $B(a,r) \cap E = \emptyset$.

So for all $x \in E$, $d(x,a) \ge r$ (or otherwise it would be a point in the ball and in $E$ at the same time, which cannot be). So the $\inf_{x \in E} d(x,a) \ge r > 0$, as $r$ is a lowerbound for the distances.